How to Deploy Multiple Widgets for One App in Xcode to Physical Device iOS 15 (Older Version)
I have an Xcode project that uses two widgets. Both work independently and build successfully together. My widget bundle file is as follows:
struct widgetBundle: WidgetBundle {
    u/WidgetBundleBuilder
    var body: some Widget {
        smallWidget()
        bigWidget()
    }
}

This gives me an error when I try to download the widgets to my physical device (iPhone 6, min OS set to 15.0). The error is as follows:
SendProcessControlEvent:toPid: encountered an error: Error Domain=com.apple.dt.deviceprocesscontrolservice Code=8 "Failed to show Widget 'com.JosiahSchatz.PGDEV.PGDWidgets' error: Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain Code=5 "The request to open "com.apple.springboard" failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The request to open "com.apple.springboard" failed., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unexpected error type., NSUnderlyingError=0x103010aa0 {Error Domain=BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain Code=3 "XPC error received on message reply handler" UserInfo={BSErrorCodeDescription=OperationFailed, NSLocalizedFailureReason=XPC error received on message reply handler}}, BSErrorCodeDescription=InvalidResponse}." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to show Widget 'com.JosiahSchatz.PGDEV.PGDWidgets' error: Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain Code=5 "The request to open "com.apple.springboard" failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The request to open "com.apple.springboard" failed., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unexpected error type., NSUnderlyingError=0x103010aa0 {Error Domain=BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain Code=3 "XPC error received on message reply handler" UserInfo={BSErrorCodeDescription=OperationFailed, NSLocalizedFailureReason=XPC error received on message reply handler}}, BSErrorCodeDescription=InvalidResponse}., NSUnderlyingError=0x103020060 {Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain Code=5 "The request to open "com.apple.springboard" failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The request to open "com.apple.springboard" failed., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unexpected error type., NSUnderlyingError=0x103010aa0 {Error Domain=BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain Code=3 "XPC error received on message reply handler" UserInfo={BSErrorCodeDescription=OperationFailed, NSLocalizedFailureReason=XPC error received on message reply handler}}, BSErrorCodeDescription=InvalidResponse}}}
Domain: DTXMessage
Code: 1
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2024-10-31 01:25:04 +0000";
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 13.6.9 (Build 22G830)
Xcode 15.2 (22503) (Build 15C500b)
Timestamp: 2024-10-30T18:25:04-07:00

However, when I comment out either widget from the bundle (as suggested here), it does not give me this error. I was wondering if there is any way to deploy both widgets at once while still being embedded in the same app.
I tried to upload one and then the other, but unless I deleted the old one first I was met by the same error. If I did delete the old one then it would go away from the widget library after downloading the new one. I tried deleting it and adding it back from the widget library, but this caused it to break, me to receive the error, and the new one to appear in the widget library. I then tried adding the old one back and both got deleted and I received the error.

Also, I am using Xcode 14
